# Conditional update within ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I have a database with table `Cities`, which has two columns `id` and `is_default` declared as integer. I would like to update all cities the way that only one city has value 1 set in `is_default` column at the same time. My database is wrapped by `ContentProvider` so I want to use `ContentResolver` for this. Here's my code:

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DEFAULT, "CASE WHEN " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID + " != " + id + " THEN 0 ELSE 1 END");
getContentResolver().update(BenefitsProvider.CITY_CONTENT_URI, contentValues, null, null);
```

Where `id` is an id of a city, which I would like to make the default one. The issue is that this query doesn't change the `is_default` column value at all. I'm sure that `ContentProvider` code is fine and it works properly with all other update cases.

Is it possible to have only one city at the same time with `is_default` column value being 1 using this approach? Is there any other way I can achieve this?